# PyArray_Check gives Segmentation Fault with Cython/C++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython

Thank you all in advance.

I am wondering what's the right way to `#include` all numpy headers and what's the right way to use Cython and C++ to parse numpy arrays. Below is attempt:

```
// cpp_parser.h 
#ifndef _FUNC_H_
#define _FUNC_H_

#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

void parse_ndarray(PyObject *);

#endif
```

I know this might be wrong, I also tried other options but none of them works.

```
// cpp_parser.cpp
#include "cpp_parser.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void parse_ndarray(PyObject *obj) {
    if (PyArray_Check(obj)) { // this throws seg fault
        cout << "PyArray_Check Passed" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "PyArray_Check Failed" << endl;
    }
}
```

The `PyArray_Check` routine throws Segmentation Fault. `PyArray_CheckExact` doesn't throw, but it is not what I wanted exactly.

```
# parser.pxd
cdef extern from "cpp_parser.h": 
    cdef void parse_ndarray(object)
```

and the implementation file is:

```
# parser.pyx
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def py_parse_array(object x):
    assert isinstance(x, np.ndarray)
    parse_ndarray(x)
```

The `setup.py` script is

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import numpy as np

ext = Extension(
    name='parser',
    sources=['parser.pyx', 'cpp_parser.cpp'],
    language='c++',
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
    extra_compile_args=['-fPIC'],
)

setup(
    name='parser',
    ext_modules=cythonize([ext])
    )
```

And finally the test script:

```
# run_test.py
import numpy as np
from parser import py_parse_array

x = np.arange(10)
py_parse_array(x)
```

I have created a git repo with all the scripts above: https://github.com/giantwhale/study_cython_numpy/

Comment: Don&amp;#39;t python functions need to be pure C? I mean, did you tried the `extern "C"` magic before function declaration and definition?

Comment: @geckos I doubt it is the reason. I would expect Cython would automatically handles this when provided with `language='C++'`. I am saying this because I also wrote a memoryview version and it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Quick Fix** (read on for more details and a more sophisticated approach):

You need  to initialize the  variable `PyArray_API` in every cpp-file in which you are using numpy-stuff by calling `import_array()`:

```
//it is only a trick to ensure import_array() is called, when *.so is loaded
//just called only once
int init_numpy(){
     import_array(); // PyError if not successful
     return 0;
}

const static int numpy_initialized =  init_numpy();

void parse_ndarraray(PyObject *obj) { // would be called every time
    if (PyArray_Check(obj)) {
        cout << "PyArray_Check Passed" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "PyArray_Check Failed" << endl;
    }
}
```

One could also use `_import_array`, which returns a negative number if not successful,  to use a custom error handling. [See here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4cc8cb27e792098875edea9fa000528ca1b34f02/numpy/core/code_generators/generate_numpy_api.py#L124) for definition of `import_array`.

**Warning:** As pointed out by @isra60, `_import_array()/import_array()` can only be called, once Python is initialized, i.e. after `Py_Initialize()` was called. This is always the case for an extension, but not always the case if the python interpreter is embedded, because `numpy_initialized` is initialized before `main`-starts. In this case, "the initialization trick" should not be used but `init_numpy()` called after `Py_Initialize()`.

---

**Sophisticated solution:**

NB: For information, why setting `PyArray_API` is needed, see this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58162089/5769463): in order to be able to postpone resolution of symbols until running time, so numpy's shared object aren't needed at link time and must not be on dynamic-library-path (python's system path is enough then).

The proposed solution is quick, but if there are more than one cpp using numpy, one have a lot of instances of PyArray_API initialized.

This can be avoided if `PyArray_API` isn't defined as static but as `extern` in all but one translation unit. For those translation units [`NO_IMPORT_ARRAY`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4cc8cb27e792098875edea9fa000528ca1b34f02/numpy/core/code_generators/generate_numpy_api.py#L28) macro must be defined before `numpy/arrayobject.h` is included.

We need however a translation unit in which this symbol is defined. For this translation unit the macro `NO_IMPORT_ARRAY` must not be defined.

However, without defining the macro `PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL` we will get only a static symbol, i.e. not visible for other translations unit, thus the linker will fail. The reason for that: if there are two libraries and everyone defines a `PyArray_API` then we would have a multiple definition of a symbol and the linker will fail, i.e. we cannot use these both libraries together.

Thus, by defining `PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL` as `MY_FANCY_LIB_PyArray_API` prior to every include of `numpy/arrayobject.h` we would have our own `PyArray_API`-name, which would not clash with other libraries.

Putting it all together:

**A:** use_numpy.h - your header for including numpy-functionality i.e. `numpy/arrayobject.h`

```
//use_numpy.h

//your fancy name for the dedicated PyArray_API-symbol
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL MY_PyArray_API 

//this macro must be defined for the translation unit              
#ifndef INIT_NUMPY_ARRAY_CPP 
    #define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY //for usual translation units
#endif

//now, everything is setup, just include the numpy-arrays:
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
```

**B:** `init_numpy_api.cpp` - a translation unit for initializing of the global `MY_PyArray_API`:

```
//init_numpy_api.cpp

//first make clear, here we initialize the MY_PyArray_API
#define INIT_NUMPY_ARRAY_CPP

//now include the arrayobject.h, which defines
//void **MyPyArray_API
#inlcude "use_numpy.h"

//now the old trick with initialization:
int init_numpy(){
     import_array();// PyError if not successful
     return 0;
}
const static int numpy_initialized =  init_numpy();
```

**C:** just include `use_numpy.h` whenever you need numpy, it will define `extern void **MyPyArray_API`:

```
//example
#include "use_numpy.h"

...
PyArray_Check(obj); // works, no segmentation error
```

**Warning:** It should not be forgotten, that for initialization-trick to work, `Py_Initialize()` must be already called.

---

**Why do you need it** (kept for historical reasons):

When I build your extension with debug symbols:

```
extra_compile_args=['-fPIC', '-O0', '-g'],
extra_link_args=['-O0', '-g'],
```

and run it with gdb:

```
 gdb --args python run_test.py
 (gdb) run
  --- Segmentation fault
 (gdb) disass
```

I can see the following:

```
   0x00007ffff1d2a6d9 <+20>:    mov    0x203260(%rip),%rax       
       # 0x7ffff1f2d940 <_ZL11PyArray_API>
   0x00007ffff1d2a6e0 <+27>:    add    $0x10,%rax
=> 0x00007ffff1d2a6e4 <+31>:    mov    (%rax),%rax
   ...
   (gdb) print $rax
   $1 = 16
```

We should keep in mind, that `PyArray_Check` is only a [define for](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7ccf0e08917d27bc0eba34013c1822b00a66ca6d/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h#L34):

```
#define PyArray_Check(op) PyObject_TypeCheck(op, &PyArray_Type)
```

That seems, that `&PyArray_Type` uses somehow a part of  `PyArray_API` which is not initialized (has value `0`).

Let's take a look at the `cpp_parser.cpp` after the preprocessor (compiled with flag `-E`:

```
 static void **PyArray_API= __null
 ...
 static int
_import_array(void)
{
  PyArray_API = (void **)PyCapsule_GetPointer(c_api,...
```

So `PyArray_AP`I is static and is initialized via `_import_array(void)`, that actually would explain the warning I get during the build, that `_import_array()` was defined but not used - we didn't initialize `PyArray_API`.

Because `PyArray_API` is a static variable it must be initialized in every compilation unit i.e. cpp - file.

So we just need to do it - `import_array()` seems to be the official way.

Comment: I also need to add    Py_Initialize(); before _import_array();

Answer (score 2):

Since you use Cython, the numpy APIs have been included in the Cython Includes already. It's straight forward in jupyter notebook.

```
cimport numpy as np
from numpy cimport PyArray_Check

np.import_array()  # Attention!

def parse_ndarray(object ndarr):
    if PyArray_Check(ndarr):
        print("PyArray_Check Passed")
    else:
        print("PyArray_Check Failed")
```

I believe `np.import_array()` is a key here, since you call into the numpy APIs. Comment it and try, a crash also appears.

```
import numpy as np
from array import array
ndarr = np.arange(3)
pyarr = array('i', range(3))
parse_ndarray(ndarr)
parse_ndarray(pyarr)
parse_ndarray("Trick or treat!")
```

Output:

```
PyArray_Check Passed
PyArray_Check Failed
PyArray_Check Failed
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply.  It is good to know we can actually do this in Cython.  However, I am really looking for ways to work with pure C++ because I have some critical piece that has to be implemented in C++.  I have added some comment at the end of my original post.