# Pass data from a C function via double pointer in Cython

Tags: c, arrays, cython, cythonize

I want to use a small C routine with Cython. The C function itself is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "examples.h"

void add_array(int **io_array, int n) {
    int i;
    int *array;

    array = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       array[i] = i;
    }

    *io_array = array;
}
```

And the function prototype:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLES_H
#define EXAMPLES_H

void add_array(int **io_array, int n);

#endif
```

Now I want to use Cython to interface the C function with:

```
cdef extern from "examples.h":
    void add_array(int **io_array, int n)


import numpy as np

def add(arr):
    if not arr.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']:
        arr = np.ascontiguousarray(arr, dtype=np.int32) 

    cdef int[::1] arr_memview = arr

    add_array(&arr_memview[0], arr_memview.shape[0])

return arr
```

When compiling it gives the error:

```
pyexamples.pyx:13:14: Cannot assign type 'int *' to 'int **'
```

What is the right way to interface this function?

Comment: I don't know enough Cython to tell you the right way to do this, but the problem is certainly that your C function is set up to both allocate and populate the (C) array.  You are passing a pointer to the array contents, but the function expects to receive a pointer to a pointer that it can update with the *location* of the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not work out-of-the-box with numpy-arrays. You will have to make the memory management yourself, for example:

```
%%cython
from libc.stdlib cimport free
def doit():
    cdef int *ptr;
    add_array(&ptr, 5)
    print(ptr[4])
    free(ptr)   #memory management
```

The difference to your attempt: `&arr_memview[0]` is pointer to an integer array, but what you need for your function is a pointer to a pointer to an integer array - that is what `&ptr` is.

---

The problem with your function is, that it has too many responsibilities:

1. it allocates the memory
2. it initializes the memory

It would be easier, if `add_array` would only be doing the second part, i.e.

```
void add_array(int *io_array, int n) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       io_array[i] = i;
    }
}
```

And thus any memory could be initialized (also memory which was not allocated with `malloc`).

---

However, it is possible to create a numpy-array using the returned pointer `ptr`, it is just less straight forward:

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

np.import_array()   # needed to initialize numpy-data structures

cdef extern from "numpy/arrayobject.h":
    void PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(np.ndarray arr, int flags) #not include in the Cython default include

def doit():
    cdef int *ptr;
    add_array(&ptr, 5)

    # create numpy-array from data:
    cdef np.npy_intp dim = 5
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] arr = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &dim, np.NPY_INT32, ptr)
    # transfer ownership of the data to the numpy array:
    PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(arr, np.NPY_OWNDATA)
    return arr
```

The following is worth mentioning:

1. [`np.import_array()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.import_array) is needed to be able to use all of the numpy's functionality. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47026900/5769463) of what can happen, if `np.import_array()` isn't called.
2. After [`PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData), the data itself isn't owned by the resulting numpy array, thus we need to enable the `OWNDATA`-flag, otherwise there will be a memory leak.
3. It is not obvious, that the resulting numpy-array can be responsible for freeing the data. For example instead of using malloc/free it could be using [Python's memory allocator](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html#the-pymalloc-allocator).

I would like to elaborate about point 3. above. Numpy uses a special function to allocate/deallocate memory for data - it is [`PyDataMem_FREE`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c#L241) and uses system's `free` for it. So in your case (using system's malloc/free in `add_array`) everything is Ok. (`PyDataMem_FREE` should not be confused with [`PyArray_free`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_free), as I did in an earlier version of the answer. `PyArray_free` is responsible for freeing other elements (array itself, and dimension/strides data, not data-memory) of the numpy-array, [see here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/59bd9ee273f26f335f1f77e0b85ede8d209a7e07/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L346) and is different depending on Python version).

A more flexible/safe approach is to use `PyArray_SetBaseObject` as shown in this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55959886/5769463).

Comment: I used your suggestions and removed the memory management from the C function. Following your solution and [link] http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#pass-data-from-a-c-function-via-pointer solves my problem.